# Transactional background jobs with grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, jesque

Is it possible to enforce transactionality in a background job from jesque from grails?

I'm using jesque-grails plugin where I can inject other services including GORM ... may I mark the job as @Transaction and expect the payload to be executed in a isolated transaction with rollback on failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying i found the answer is yes. You can simply mark the job as @Transactional and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`@Transactional` works on controllers and services (though it's use on controller actions is not generally recommended). I don't know if it will work on jesque jobs, but it should be pretty easy to find out, i.e. save something, then throw a `RuntimeException` and see if the saved data is rolled back.

If you can't annotate your method with `@Transactional` you could instead wrap the method in [withTransaction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html)